# Cannot access data from jQuery Ajax request, returns empty array

Tags: php, ajax, forms, jquery

I have a form that is called via the [fancybox plugin](http://fancybox.net/blog) login example.

Here is the code I have:

Form:

```
<form method="post" action="" id="events_form">
    <p class="clearfix"><label for="Name">Name:</label> <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" /></p>
    <p class="clearfix"><label for="Company">Company:</label> <input type="text" name="Company" id="Company" /></p>
    <p class="clearfix"><label for="Email">Email:</label> <input type="text" name="Email" id="Email" /></p>
    <p class="clearfix"><label for="Tel">Tel:</label> <input type="text" name="Tel" id="Tel"/></p>
    <p class="clearfix"><input type="submit" value="Submit details" /></p>
 </form>
```

JavaScript / jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#event_trigger").fancybox({
            'padding'  : 0,
            'scrolling'  : 'no',
            'titleShow'  : false,
        });

        $("#events_form").bind("submit", function() {
            $.fancybox.showActivity();

            $.ajax({
                type  : "POST",
                cache : false,
                url  : "/events/index.php",
                data  : $(this).serializeArray(),
                success: function(data) {
                    $.fancybox(data);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

The PHP file returns and empty array. However the [Firebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug_%28software%29) post tab displays the form data.

Also, I noticed that if I do

```
print_r($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])
```

This returns GET, even though I have specified POST.

Comment: you could try to use $.post() function

Comment: I've tried using $.post(), problems remains unfortunately

Comment: Why not using [jQuery form plugins](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form)? It will make your work easier.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).serializeArray()
```

with the name of the form CSS id (#my-form-ID, in this example) like this:

```
$("#my-form-ID").serializeArray()
```

Hope that solves it. It worked for me. ;-D

Answer (score 0):

`$.ajax` expects the parameter `data` to be an object or a string.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ scroll down to data.

If you wrap your `data` in an object e.g. `data: {array:$(this).serializeArray()}` it may work. I'm not 100% sure on that though.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, unfortunately wrapping data didn't work.

Comment: What do you get if you add textStatus to your success function e.g. `function(data, textStatus){alert(textStatus);}`?

Comment: thats returns "Success", still an empty array though.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing an AJAX request on a form submit.

Unless the AJAX request is synchronous (which I wouldn't recommend, anyway) there is a danger that your form will be submitted before there is any chance for the AJAX request will return.

In the line:

```
$(this).serializeArray()
```

$(this) is referring to the the form element you have selected in the bind method. I'm assuming this is intended

Comment: Hi, yes this is intended. I got this code from the example on http://fancybox.net/blog and the example works fine.