# Empty collections not present in JSON request

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, collections, sinatra

I have a Sinatra app and I'm updating some stuff in a mongoDB database with some PUT-requests.

In javascript, the actual values I'm posting are:

```
entity: {
    config: someString,
    parameters: parameterArray, // EMPTY [ ]
    dt: dtArray, // EMPTY [ ]
}
```

I'm doing this via jQuery ajax.

On the server side I get the following:

```ruby
params[:entity] #=> config = someString
```

But the empty arrays are missing. Why is this? I need them! The same route will handle both empty arrays and no parameter at all in a different way...

Comment: Try this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397669/jquery-ajax-jsonp-how-to-actually-send-an-array-even-if-its-empty

Comment: @cfs I feared so much yes... Problem is it makes a huge difference in my app if it's an empty array or just nothing at all...

Comment: The first workaround that comes to mind is to add `parameterCount` and `dtCount` properties, and that way you can specify `0` for an empty array, but to represent "nothing" you'd either leave the `count` properties out or specify `null` or `-1`. (Then, in case it's not blindingly obvious, server-side you'd test the count properties first and decide what to do from there.)

Comment: @nnnnnn I did something similar but I just had one element in the arrays, an empty string.

Comment: Cool. That's obviously fine as long as an empty string isn't an otherwise valid value. There're lots of variations on either idea...