# Sending empty arrays to the server using jQuery post or similar Asynchronous JavaScript request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Given

```
$.post('dealWithStuff.php',{'fullArray':['hello','goodby'],'emptyArray':[]});
```

dealWithStuff.php receives

```
['fullArray'=>['hello','goodby'] ]
```

but not

```
['fullArray'=>['hello','goodby'], 'emptyArray'=>[] ]
```

How do I send the emptyArray to the server?

Comment: What's the code you use to print that debugging text out?

Comment: @Blender  PHP?  Do you feel I shouldn't see these results?

Comment: Whoops, I thought you were sending this as JSON. You can't send an empty array as a POST parameter because it would be indistinguishable from `['']`. Encode your object as JSON and decode it with PHP to preserve the structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give this a crack.

Just before we start, [`This would be a good question for you to read over.`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9397669/2518525)

You can't send an empty array because it'd look something like this: `file.php?arra[]`.

You'll need to do this when sending:

```
$.post('dealWithStuff.php',{'fullArray':['hello','goodby'],'emptyArray':['']});
```

Notice how `emptyArray` is **`['']`** instead of **`[]`** ?
This will give you a response that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [fullArray] => Array
        (
            [0] => hello
            [1] => goodby
        )

    [emptyArray] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

)
```

You'll be able to access it from the backend, you'll just have to remove that child array element from within the `emptyArray`.

easily done with something like this:

```
foreach($_POST['emptyArray'] as $i => $derp) {
    unset($_POST['emptyArray'][$i]);
}
```

*Presuming you don't want any items in the `emptyArray`*.
After that, you'll get a return that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [fullArray] => Array
        (
            [0] => hello
            [1] => goodby
        )

    [emptyArray] => Array
        (
        )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use null which is  [legal value in JSON](http://www.json.org).

Just for the sake of curiosity, why would you send an empty array to server? You just could check server-side if array is set. [(isset() for php)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

Comment: There is absolutely no JSON mentioned in this question.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really make sense to send an empty array. Think about what the browser would send to the server. The data that is sent for your post would be:

```
fullArray[]:hello
fullArray[]:goodby
```

Which would be translated in PHP as:

```
$_POST['fullArray'] = array(0 => "hello", 1 => "goodby");
```

But if you were to send say,

```
emptyArray[]:
```

It would be treated as an empty string value and you'll get something like:

```
$_POST['emptyArray'] = array(0 => "");
```

Which is probably not what you want (and not what jQuery does). Change your back-end if possible to detect the existence of the key.

Comment: Changing the backend doesn't fix it.  What I need is for the server to receive the "emptyArray" key, and when no elements are attached, know to do something else.  That being said, I do appreciate your answer and will mull over it some more.

Comment: Have a key called ```emptyArrays``` which contains a list of strings representing arrays that are empty, and manipulate/populate it on the front-end upon form-submit. Your other alternative is to send all the data through a single key (maybe ```data```) and send a serialized version of the object (JSON) into your server. Then you can simply ```json_decode``` it.

Comment: -1 for "*change your backend to detect the existence*". It is jQuery on the client side that eats the parameter, as you can easily test.

Comment: @Bergi Nobody is disputing that? Which means the key no longer exists when the PHP receives the data, telling you that that array was empty.

Comment: Did you mean "change the backend to detect whether the key is present, and treat it as empty otherwise"? Your current phrasing sounds like the PHP should detect the non-existant key.